# "Confirm Mac password" error

Tags: mac, password, error, apple-silicon, ventura

I have an M1 Mac and after updating to macOS Ventura I am asked to confirm my Mac password in the settings app. However, when I type in the correct password, my Mac rejects it as if it was wrong. I have checked it, and also copied it from TextEdit (so that I can see it in clear text to be sure it is correct), but it is still treated as wrong.

What can I do?

Edit: It is exactly like in this tutorial, except that my correct Mac password is not accepted:

https://osxdaily.com/2022/12/29/fix-confirm-mac-password-to-keep-using-icloud-in-system-settings/

Comment: *"confirm my Mac password"* Where? By what? For what process/task?

Comment: Perhaps a screenshot would help too. Please [edit] your question to add a screenshot and answer the questions above.